# Adding Upload Progress handler to XMLHTTPRequest object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, xmlhttprequest

I am writing a function to upload files. Below is the sample code :

```
function UploadFile(caller: Event, form: HTMLFormElement) {
// Prevent the default action
caller.preventDefault();

// Create and open the request
let ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajaxRequest.open(form.method, form.action);
ajaxRequest.upload.onprogress.call(UpdateProgress);

if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
    form.reset();
    document.getElementById('UploadedFilePath').innerText = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }

let fData = new FormData(form);
}

function UpdateProgress(req: XMLHttpRequest, ev: ProgressEvent) {
if (ev.lengthComputable) {
    let max = ev.total;
    let current = ev.loaded;

    let Percentage: number = Math.round((current * 100) / max);
    document.getElementById('UploadProgress').innerText = Percentage.toString();
    }
}
```

The application fails at "ajaxRequest.upload.onprogress.call(UpdateProgress);". I believe i've made some mistake here. So, can somebody please point on how to correctly assign the handler to the Progress Event.

Comment: Call doesn't work like that, it takes `(this, ...args)`, so you would be calling UploadProgress with `(UploadProgress().bind(UploadProgress))`

Change it to `ajaxRequest.upload.onprogress = (function(event){ UpdateProgress(null, event);
 }).bind(ajaxRequest);`

Comment: Tried this "ajaxRequest.upload.onprogress = function (event) { UpdateProgress(null, event); }.bind(ajaxRequest);" and it didn't work.

Comment: You removed two brackets it makes `bind` fail because it doesn't work on function declarations

Comment: Okay, this doesn't work either "ajaxRequest.upload.onprogress = (function (event) { UpdateProgress(null, event); }).bind(ajaxRequest);"

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of null.

Comment: Oops !! That was due to the Build did not really build the TypeScript file. Now i am not getting the error. But the event is not being triggered.

Comment: Try putting progress first, this is from mozilla `Note: You need to add the event listeners before calling open() on the request. Otherwise the progress events will not fire.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177883/discussion-between-praveen-rai-and-pavlo).

Comment: You don't even need to use bind, since the target is the XMLHttpRequest to begin with. You can just use `this`

Comment: @Pavlo Thanks, i got this working finally : ajaxRequest.upload.onprogress = (function(event){ UpdateProgress(null, event); }).bind(ajaxRequest);

Comment: @mpm Can you please share a code snippet ?